# Why can (and must) the variable x appear twice on the left side of the function definition? And what's the meaning?

Tags: idris

I'm a green hand with Idris,and get confused with this definition, as I don't understand how it works.
The definitionare as follows.

```
sameS : (k : Nat)->(j : Nat)->(k = j)->((S k) = (S j))
sameS x x Refl=Refl
```

Answer (score 3):

Let us start by breaking down the type signature:

```
sameS : (k : Nat) -> (j : Nat) -> (k = j) -> ((S k) = (S j))
```

`sameS` is a function.
`sameS` take the following arguments:

1. `(k : Nat)` a parameter `k` of type `Nat`
2. `(j : Nat)` a parameter `j` of type `Nat`
3. `(k = j)` A proof that `k` and `j` are equal

`sameS` returns:

`((S k) = (S j))` proof that `S k` and `S j` are equal.

Now let us breakdown the definition:

```
sameS x x Refl = Refl
```

The type of `Refl` is `a = a`.

`x` is both the first and second argument because both are identical.                                          We know this because the 3rd argument is `Refl`.

`Refl` is returned because `S x = S x`.